# Write to own executable in Linux C program, error "Text file busy"

Tags: c, security, permissions, binary, self-modifying

For a security class I am supposed to write self-modifying code for a program which finds its own executable on the disk, reads the binary data, and encrypts part of it before writing it back out to the disk. This is supposed to be like a polymorphic virus which changes itself to fool antivirus scanners which detect known signatures.

I have all the pieces pretty much in place:

- I am finding the executable using `/proc/self/exe`.
- I am using a simple AES implementation to encrypt 16 byte string in some dummy code in the executable.
- I am able to read the binary data in and locate the part I need to encrypt.

My problem is that the only way I have been able to open the executable is in read-only mode `"rb"`. If I try to open the file for writing in mode `"wb"` or `"r+b"` I get back the error `"Text file busy"`. Is there anyway for me to write to a process's own executable in C? Can I do this by changing the permissions somehow?

**EDIT:** What I am trying to accomplish is to have an executable which will encrypt part of itself each time that it runs so that it will have a new checksum after every time it runs.

After reading data from the executable binary, how can I either write back to it or remove it and replace it with a new file with the same filename?

Comment: Try copying yourself (in read only mode), executing the copy, then deleting the original from the copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write to a file that is currently mapped as an executable. However, you can write to a file that has the *same path* as the current executable, so long as it isn't actually the same file — try unlinking the file you're being executed from and creating a new file in its place, for instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? By the *same path* do you mean a new file created in the same directory as the current executable, but with a different file name? By *unlink* do you mean using this [`unlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) function?

Comment: Yes, you can `unlink()` or move (`link()` then `unlink()`) the executable.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do what I needed with with the `unlink` function. I first open the executable binary in mode `"rb"`, read in the data, close the file, unlink the file, open a new file to be written at the same path in mode `"wb"`, write the modified binary data, close the file, then I use `chmod` to mark the new file as executable.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do self modification too, I wrote a small code in nasm (which can be used as a stub), which opens itself and at the middle of the code (right after the mmap), we have a pointer which points to the bytes of the executable that we can modify.

The code looks like this:

```
BITS 64

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call _main__

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0x0
    syscall ; exit(0);

_main__:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 144 ; stat_file
    mov rdi, [rbp+0x18]
    lea rsi, [rsp]
    call _open_self ; open self
    push r12 ; len file
    push rax ; addr
    mov r14, rsi

    

    mov rdi, [rbp+0x18] ; pathname
    pop rsi ; addr
    pop rdx ; len
    push rdx
    push rsi
    call __create
    mov r13, rax ; second fd

    mov rdi, r14 ; fd
    pop rsi ; addr -> mmap
    pop rdx ; len_file
    call __close_unmap

    mov rax, 87
    mov rdi, [rbp+0x18]
    syscall

    mov rax, 0x3 ; close(scnd_fd);
    mov rdi, r13
    syscall

    mov rax, 86
    push 'nasm'
    lea rdi, [rsp]
    mov rsi, [rbp+0x18]
    syscall ; link tmp name to original name

    mov rax, 87
    lea rdi, [rsp]
    syscall ; delete old tmp file

    leave
    ret


; ===============================

; Open himself
_open_self:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov r15, rsi ; &stat_file
    mov r12, rdi ; *pathname

    mov rax, 0x2
    mov rsi, 0x0 ; 0_RD
    mov rdx, 509
    syscall

    push rax ; fd

    mov rdi, rax ; fd
    mov rsi, r15 ; struct stat
    mov rax, 5 ; fstat
    syscall

    xor rdi, rdi
    mov rsi, qword [r15+48]
    mov rdx, 0x4
    mov r10, 0x2
    pop r8
    push r8
    mov r9, 0x0
    mov rax, 9
    syscall ; mmap

    ; rax -> byte of the executable that we gonna dump

    mov r12, qword [r15+48]

    pop rsi ; fd
    leave
    ret

; ===============================

; int __create(const char *pathname, void *addr, ssize_t len_bytes_mapped);

__create:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rsi ; addr
    push rcx ; len

    push 'nasm'
    lea rdi, [rsp]
    mov rax, 0x2
    mov rsi, 0x42 ; 0_CREAT | O_RDWR
    mov rdx, 509
    syscall ; sys_open

    add rsp, 0x8 ; 'nasm'
    mov r9, rax ; fd
    mov rdi, rax ; fd

    mov rax, 0x1
    pop rdx
    pop rsi
    syscall ; sys_write

    mov rax, r9 ; fd final

    leave
    ret

; int __close_unmap(int fd, unsigned lon addr, ssize_t len_file);

__close_unmap:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    push rdi

    mov rdi, rsi
    mov rsi, rdx
    mov rax, 11
    syscall ; munmap(addr, len_file)

    pop rdi
    mov rax, 3
    syscall ; close(fd);

    leave
    ret
```

It is a bit long but it makes just :

-Open it self in read mode (O_RD == 0x0)

-Do a stat(*pathname, &buffer_struct_stat);

-And then a mmap(0, buffer_struct_stat.st_size, 0x4, MAP_PRIVATE, fd_read_only, 0);

-Here you can edit your executable by editing the bytes at the address returned by mmap

-Create a tmp file named "nasm"

-Do a write(fd_tmp, address_of_mmap, buffer_struct_stat.st_size)

-Close the two file descriptors and munmap the mmap

-Now it's cool : unlink(pathname) and link("nasm", "pathname")